# Kotlin keep reference to class and update

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm confused around member reference in Kotlin. I have a custom class that once I create an instance of it i execute api work. I keep a list of these instances of the class - once the api work has completed I want the list of the instances to be updated. In swift reference types handle this but I'm unsure how to implement in Kotlin.

So my code:
MY custom class:

```
    class MyCustomClass(var firstName: String, var lastName:String, var profilePictureUrl:String= EMPTY_STRING){
        
        fun getUsersProfilePicture(){
//api code executed here to fetch the users profile picture
            profilePictureUrl = api result
        }
    }
```

when I create an instance of this object I add to an array list in my viewmodel

```
var myClass = MyCustomClass("firstName", "lastName")
myClass.getUsersProfilePicture()
list.add(myClass)
```

The api function executes fine but the instance in my list is not updated with this value.
How do I update the object in my list once the api task has returned with the correct image?

Comment: Is `getUsersProfilePicture` async and executed in different thread? If so, try to add `@Volatile` to `profilePictureUrl`, `@Volatile var profilePictureUrl: String = ...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! @Volatile was exactly what I needed! You should answer the question and I will mark it as the correct answer! Thank you so much ☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning the result in different thread, add `@Volatile` ([java volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)) so that other threads can see the changes

```
@Volatile var profilePictureUrl: String = ...
```